# Java output like a chessboard

Tags: java

I have to make that output in Java:

x0x0x0x0

0x0x0x0x

x0x0x0x0

0x0x0x0x

x0x0x0x0

0x0x0x0x

x0x0x0x0

0x0x0x0x

Until now it looks like that:

x0x0x0x0

x0x0x0x0

x0x0x0x0

x0x0x0x0

x0x0x0x0

x0x0x0x0

x0x0x0x0

x0x0x0x0

Can you help me? Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1;
    for (n = 1; n < 65; n++) {

        if (n%2==0) {
            TextIO.putf("O");

        } else {
            TextIO.putf("x");
        }
        if (n%8==0) {
            TextIO.putln();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what @kocko said. Use one loop to print the new lines and the inner loop to print each character of the line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
    for(int i =1;i<9*8;i++){
        if (i%9==0)         System.out.println();
        else if (i%2==0)    System.out.print(i%2);
        else                System.out.print(i%2);      
    }
```